# Looping in sql query

Tags: oracle

I want to add one additional row to the my query output when ever the value of column 'Month' is Feb.

Please see the example:

```
SQL> select * from CUSTOMER;
CUST_ID MONTH           SPEND
```

---

```
     1 Jan               100
     1 Feb               200
     1 Apr                20
     2 Jan               145
     2 Mar                50
     3 May               100
     4 Feb               250
```

-----Output Required------

```
CUST_ID MONTH                          SPEND
```

---

```
     1 Jan                              100
     1 Feb                              200
     1 Feb-Reversal                    -200
     1 Apr                               20
     2 Jan                              145
     2 Mar                              50
     3 May                              100
     4 Feb                              250
     4 Feb-Reversal                    -250
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (cust_id NUMBER, month VARCHAR2(3), spend NUMBER);

INSERT INTO customer VALUES (1, 'Jan', 100);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (1, 'Feb', 200);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (1, 'Apr', 20);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (2, 'Jan', 145);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (2, 'Mar', 50);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (3, 'May', 100);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (4, 'Feb', 250); 

COMMIT;

SELECT cust_id, month, spend
  FROM customer
UNION ALL
SELECT cust_id, month || '-Reversal', -spend
  FROM customer
WHERE month = 'Feb'
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Check at SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0ad222/1

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
WITH t(ID_, mon, VALUE_) as
(
SELECT 1, 'Jan', 100 FROM dual
union
SELECT 1, 'Feb',200 FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 1, 'Apr',20 FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 2, 'Jan',145 FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 2, 'Mar',50 FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 3, 'May',100 FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 4, 'Feb',250 FROM dual
)     
SELECT id_, mon, value_ 
FROM (
     SELECT id_, mon, value_ FROM t
     UNION 
     SELECT id_, mon ||'-Reversal', value_ * -1 FROM T WHERE MON = 'Feb'
)
ORDER BY id_;
```